# How can I make Rasdial execute again if a connection is not yet available?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

The following command (applicable to PPPoE connection) is in a .bat file.

```
Rasdial "connection name" "user name" "password"
```

How can I make it execute again automatically if it fails (i.e. connection is not yet available)?

Comment: "Fails" in what way?

Comment: Connection is not yet available.

Comment: It looks like you're using Windows. Which version?

Comment: Windows 7 64-bit Home Premium in traditional Chinese.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a(nother) batch (e.g.: BatchFile.bat) file that contains:

```
:Dial
Rasdial Connection_Name Username Password

if %errorlevel% GTR 0 goto Dial
```

Then call `Start "" BatchFile.bat` from your original batch file.

When RASDial exits normally it will exit with errorlevel 0.

The If statement checks to see if the error level returned by the previous program (RASDial in this case) is greater than 0, and if it is, it assumes there's an error and jumps back to try the dial again.  Otherwise it just continues on.

Comment: it could be either `%errorlevel% gtr 0` or `errorlevel 1` . This will may be also handy if OP wants to test for specific error/exit code: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530704%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @ Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 and wmz,  it works. But how can I make the window close automatically when it is complete?

Comment: @matthewwai I'd day that's a candidate for a separate question. :)

Comment: How can I make it stop automatically after three re-dials?

Comment: Hey, @MatthewWai, about your edit ("Comment: `GTR` doesn't work, but `gtr` does."), those Windows commands are not case sensitive. Test again because the issue would be other than that. For instance, I used `dir *.axe & if %errorlevel% gtr 0 echo.1 & if %errorlevel% GTR 0 echo.1`and `dir *.* & if %errorlevel% gtr 0 echo.1 & if %errorlevel% GTR 0 echo.1` with `GTR` and `gtr` and it works the same way, but both appears to show some delay on showing `1` after changing the command line.

Comment: I.e. edit rejected and a homework for you - check issues on detecting `errorlevel` :)

Comment: @ kokbira, I think it didn't work at my end because I had used errorlevel GTR before it was changed to %errorlevel% GTR by Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007.

Answer (score 0):

I just found that my original .bat file can simply be deleted, and I can just use a single .bat file containing the following commands to do the whole job including re-dial when fails.

:DIAL
Rasdial "connection name" "user name" "password"
If errorlevel 1 goto DIAL